# Check if Command Line Argument - C Programming

Tags: c, if-statement, command-line-arguments

I am trying to write code that says if there is command line input then do something if not do something else.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int lowerBound, upperBound, i, count = 0;
    float val;
    char c;

    if(argc = 2)
    {
        lowerBound = argv[1];
        printf("Lower bound = %d", lowerBound);

        item * curr, * head;
        head = NULL;

        do
        {
            printf("Enter a number: ");
            scanf("%f", &val);
            curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));

            if(val >= lowerBound)
            {
                curr->num = val;
                curr->next = head;
                head = curr;
                count++;
            }

            getchar();
            printf("Want to enter another number (y/n):  ");
            scanf("%c", &c);
        } while( c != 'n' && c != 'N' );

        curr = head;

        float largest = findLargest(curr);
        float lowest = findSmallest(curr);
        float mean = findMean(curr, count);
        int ValuesAboveMean = valuesAboveMean(curr, mean);
        int ValuesBelowOrAtMean = valuesBelowOrAtMean(curr, mean);
        float median = findMedian(curr, count);
        show(count, lowest, largest, mean, median, ValuesAboveMean,    ValuesBelowOrAtMean);
    }
    else if(argc = 3)
    {
        lowerBound = argv[1];
        upperBound = argv[2];
        printf("Lower bound = %d", lowerBound);
        printf("Upper bound = %d", upperBound);
        item * curr, * head;
        head = NULL;

        do
        {
            printf("Enter a number: ");
            scanf("%f", &val);
            curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));

            if(val >= lowerBound && val <= upperBound)
            {
                curr->num = val;
                curr->next = head;
                head = curr;
                count++;
            }

            getchar();
            printf("Want to enter another number (y/n):  ");
            scanf("%c", &c);
        } while( c != 'n' && c != 'N' );

            curr = head;

            float largest = findLargest(curr);
            float lowest = findSmallest(curr);
            float mean = findMean(curr, count);
            int ValuesAboveMean = valuesAboveMean(curr, mean);
            int ValuesBelowOrAtMean = valuesBelowOrAtMean(curr, mean);
            float median = findMedian(curr, count);
            show(count, lowest, largest, mean, median, ValuesAboveMean, ValuesBelowOrAtMean);
        }
        else if(argc = 1 or argc = 0 or argc = NULL)
        {
            item * curr, * head;
            head = NULL;

            do
            {
                printf("Enter a number: ");
                scanf("%f", &val);
                curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));

                curr->num = val;
                curr->next = head;
                head = curr;
                count++;

            getchar();
            printf("Want to enter another number (y/n):  ");
            scanf("%c", &c);
        } while( c != 'n' && c != 'N' );

         curr = head;

        float largest = findLargest(curr);
        float lowest = findSmallest(curr);
        float mean = findMean(curr, count);
        int ValuesAboveMean = valuesAboveMean(curr, mean);
        int ValuesBelowOrAtMean = valuesBelowOrAtMean(curr, mean);
        float median = findMedian(curr, count);
        show(count, lowest, largest, mean, median, ValuesAboveMean, ValuesBelowOrAtMean);
        }
```

For some reason or another currently, it ignores what is in the if statements and runs whatever is in the if. For instance, even if I have no command line arguments, it still wants to run the first if where arg = 2.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make that if(argc == 2)

(instead of if(argc = 2), which assigns 2 to argc and will always be true). I never liked the way C defined = versus == . Some compilers will produce a warning for this.

Comment: Also explains why some people write `if (2 = argc)` - That WILL give you a warning everytime (if you forget the 2nd `=`)

Comment: Wow thanks, I feel really dumb. Just learning C in a class I'm taking. As you can see I have a ways to go :)

Comment: Don't feel bad, I saw the same error in a rarely used path in what was considered to be old and stable code made by a team of programmers, only to get triggered by a special sequence of events used in a later system test.